# Send data based on Button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities. 1st activity has got 3 buttons. These buttons have text as C1, C2 and C3. For example, if I click button2, second activity should display 'C2' in TextView. Or if button1 is clicked in first activity 'C1' should be displayed in the 2nd activity. And the same for button3. I have used intent to move data from one activity to another, but the problem is that when I press button1 or button2, noting is displayed in 2nd activity but, when  I press  button3, 'C3' is displayed. So what should I do to display for button1 and button2?

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question

Comment: @PPartisan okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the first layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcLvC.png)

code as following

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="c1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:text="c2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:text="c3"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

second layout as following

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

for main activity you have 3 button as following

```
Button btn1 , btn2 , btn3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            String str = btn1.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("text",str);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            String str = btn2.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("text",str);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            String str = btn3.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("text",str);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

and for your second activity

```
 TextView textView ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");

    textView.setText(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, you can create a `static` variable in you `first_activity` then when the button is clicked you set that variable. And in the next activity you access that varibale like this

```
  first_activity.variable
```

and you set it to your `TextView`.

Of course this is not the best answer, but I wish you can post what you have tried maybe I can help you fix your approach.